# Network propagation delay and forks in Proof of Stake?

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-stake

I am learning the fundamental of Proof of Stake (PoS), i came accross a question which i could not find answer to. Assume we have three validators (aka miners in PoW), V1, V2 and V3. Each of the validators controls 1/3 of the total stake? If PoS is designed to have a block generated each 5 seconds. at time=5 V1 was assigned to generate a block B1 and send it to other verifiers. Due to propagation delay, V2 was assigned to generated B2 at time =10, but at that time he has not received B1 yet .

In PoW, V2 will generate another version of B1 "a competitive block", so this refers to a fork, and at the end either V1 or V2 will win the block.

My question, does this will be the case for PoS? if not, how it works then?

Answer (score 1):

yes that's the case for PoS it will fork into 2 branch and the job of PoS is to choose which chain to follow. The way to do it is different for every protocol like in casper ffg:

> FOLLOW THE CHAIN CONTAINING THE JUSTIFIED CHECKPOINT OF THE GREATEST HEIGHT